# Injective or constant function on measurable cardinal

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, filters, large-cardinals

I'm working on the following question:

> Let $\kappa$ regular cardinal, and $f:\kappa \rightarrow \kappa$.
>
> 1. Prove that $\{\alpha < \kappa\mid f|_\alpha : \alpha \rightarrow \alpha\}$ is a club set
> 2. $\kappa$ is measurable. Let $U$, non-trivial, normal, $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$. Prove that there exists $X \in U$ such that $f$ is constant on $X$, or $f$ is injective on $X$

Solved the first part, but I'm not sure what to do with the second part.

Thanks!

**Edit:** (definitions)

We defined the relation

> $f \leq_U g \iff \{\alpha < \kappa \mid f(\alpha) \leq g(\alpha)\} \in U$

and proved that it is a well ordering on the equivalence classes of $\kappa \rightarrow On$ under $=_U$. Then we defined $U$ is normal iff $id$ is the minimal function above the constant functions in this ordering.

Comment: How did you define a normal measure? (There are several equivalent characterizations)

Comment: (Also use `\mid` as a separator in the definition of a set, rather than `|`. The spacing is correct that way and not "cramped up".)

Comment: @AsafKaragila We didn't define normal measure, we defined a normal filter, not sure if this is what we need but I added the definition to the post.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks, I didn't notice it was cramped :)

Comment: In the context of measurable cardinals, $\kappa$-complete ultrafilters on $\kappa$ are often called "measures", and normal measures correspond to normal ultrafilters.

Comment: Did you prove that every club is in $U$ and that $U$ is closed under diagonal intersections of length $\kappa$ (for normal filters)?

Comment: You need to add in line 2 the assumption that $\kappa$ is uncountable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, we didn't prove it... I suspected something like that because of part 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a coloring $c:[\kappa]^2 \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ as follows $c(\{\alpha, \beta\}) = 0$ iff $f(\alpha) = f(\beta)$. Let $d:\kappa \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ be defined by $d(\alpha) = 0$ if $A_{\alpha} = \{\beta < \kappa: c(\{\alpha, \beta\}) = 0\} \in U$ and $d(\alpha) = 1$ if $B_{\alpha} = \{\beta < \kappa : c(\{\alpha, \beta\}) = 1\} \in U$. Then $d$ is constant on a set $X \in U$.

Suppose for every $\alpha \in X$, $d(\alpha) = 0$. Then by normality of $U$, the diagonal intersection of $A_{\alpha}$'s, $D = \{\alpha < \kappa : (\forall \beta < \alpha)(\alpha \in A_{\beta})\} \in U$. For any $\beta < \alpha$ in $D$ we have $\alpha \in A_{\beta}$ so $c(\{\alpha, \beta\}) = 0$. Hence $f$ is constant on $D$.

The case when $d$ is $1$ on $X$ is dealt similarly.

Addendum: If $W = \kappa \backslash D \in U$, then the function $r:W \rightarrow \kappa$ defined by $r(\alpha) = \text{least } \beta \text{ such that } \alpha \notin A_{\beta}$ is regressive, non constant on a set in $U$ and below the identity.

Comment: While true, and probably the easiest way to solve this, the OP mentioned in the comment that the fact that normality implies (or rather equivalent) to closure under diagonal intersections is unavailable yet.

Comment: I added an argument for that.

Comment: Isn't it the case that $f$ is constant on $A_\alpha$? So, if $d(\alpha)= 0$ for some $\alpha$, we're done? For instance, any two ordinals $\beta, \delta\in A_\alpha$ will be such that $f(\beta) = f(\alpha) = f(\delta)$, trivially. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right. The hard work is for the case when d is identically 1.