# Any measurable cardinal has a chain or antichain of the same cardinality.

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

Some time ago I got an answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635695/injective-or-constant-function-on-measurable-cardinal) old exam question addressing cardinals. Now I found the similar question.

Let $\kappa$ be a measurable cardinal, and $\preceq$ a partial ordering on $\kappa$. Prove that first and/or second property holds.

1. exists an $A \subset \kappa$ of cardinality $\kappa$ s.t. $A$ is an antichain which is a set of pairwise incomparable elements.
2. there exists $L \subset \kappa$ of cardinality $\kappa$ s.t. $\preceq$ is linear on $L$.

This question can be solved using a similar technique to the one illustrated in the previous question. Can we say that since $\kappa$ is measurable, it is Ramsey, and therefore we have an homogeneous set of cardinality $\kappa$ for the function:
$$
f(\{x,y\}) = \begin{cases}
1 & (x \preceq y) \vee (y \preceq x)\\ 
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$ 
and be done with it?

Comment: $L\subset\kappa$ of cardinality $\kappa$, or do you mean of measure $1$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I meant of cardinality $\kappa$. I will fix it.

Comment: If, by antichain, you mean a set of pairwise incomparable elements then yes you are done with it. But sometimes antichain means a set of pairwise incompatible elements - where two elements are incompatible if there is nothing below both of them.

Comment: I guess antichain means pairwise incomparable here because there are obvious counterexamples under the other interpretation so you are indeed done.

Comment: @hot_queen Thanks! I've just read the proof for Ramsey cardinals, which reminded me of your answer from the linked question. Do you want to write this comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: You already had the solution so you should perhaps write your own version of a more detailed answer.

Comment: @hot_queen: I don't think that in this context antichain would mean pairwise incompatible elements...

Comment: Asaf, Yes. I agree.

Comment: Hila, how did the exam go?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not good enough for me to be happy about it, not bad enough to make moed b mandatory. "Luckily", moadei b are held during the summer vacation, so I have some time to think whether I want to go through it again. Thanks for asking :)

Comment: @Hila: I see. That's too bad. I'll be waiting for you here, in case you decide to retake the exam and need more help. ;-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks... :)

Comment: So, did you think it over?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Not going to happen - I have too much work :) Thanks!

Comment: Well, good luck, then.